# Calculate total area of polygons in shapefile using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, ogr, area, ogrinfo

I have a shapefile in British National Grid projection:

```
Geometry: 3D Polygon
Feature Count: 5378
Extent: (9247.520209, 14785.170099) - (638149.173223, 1217788.569952)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["British_National_Grid",
    GEOGCS["GCS_airy",
        DATUM["OSGB_1936",
            SPHEROID["Airy_1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",49],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-2],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996012717],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",400000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",-100000],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
cat: Integer (9.0)
```

Can I use GDAL/OGR to get the total area of all the polygons in the shapefile, in hectares?

I'm wondering if this is possible with `-sql`, something like:

```
ogrinfo -sql "SELECT SUM(ST_Area(geom::geography)) FROM mytable" myshapefile.shp
```

But trying that I get `ERROR 1: Undefined function 'ST_Area' used.`.

I guess I could import the Shapefile into QGIS, add an area attribute to each polygon, and then sum it, but I would much rather use a command line tool if possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a special field in OGR SQL called **OGR_GEOM_AREA** which returns the area of the feature's geometry:

```
ogrinfo -sql "SELECT SUM(OGR_GEOM_AREA) AS TOTAL_AREA FROM myshapefile" myshapefile.shp
```

where `TOTAL_AREA` unit of measure depends by the layer SRS (read the comments below).

Comment: Amazing! This gives me `SUM_OGR_GEOM_AREA (Real) = 4459037129.50955`. Is this in hectares or some other unit? And does it matter what projection my source shapefile is in?

Comment: The unit of measure derives from how your geometries are projected, so they are square meters.

Comment: most likely in m^2, divide by 10000 to convert to hectares

Comment: Thanks! I just found the docs: http://www.gdal.org/classOGRSurface.html#a3b2c3125ec8c0b3a986e43cd1056f9e4 **Returns the area of the feature in square units of the spatial reference system in use**. Sorry to be a total beginner, but just in case I'm using a shapefile in a different SRS, how do I find out what the square units of a particular SRS are?

Comment: Looking in your layer SRS WKT (i.e. the projection file), you will find UNIT["Meter",1]]

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to use the OGR [SQLite dialect](http://gdal.org/1.11/ogr/ogr_sql_sqlite.html) as follows:

```
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql 'SELECT SUM(ST_Area(geometry))/10000 FROM myshapefile' myshapefile.shp
```

Also, ensure that `myshapefile` is the layer name in `myshapefile.shp`. You can do this as follows:

```
ogrinfo myshapefile.shp

INFO: Open of `myshapefile.shp`
    using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: myshapefile (Polygon)
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I see `no such column: geometry`. How do I find out what the geometry column is called? This is the output of `ogrinfo -al -fid 1`: `OGRFeature(mylayer):1
  cat (Integer) = 2
  POLYGON ((463267.036276041297242 1216886.583904854720458 0,463267.693611663184129 1216956.525473011657596 0,463405.369117364054546 1216820.109560555079952 0,463404.712737055611797 1216750.1665881925728170,463267.036276041297242 1216886.583904854720458 0,463267.036276041297242 1216886.583904854720458 0))`.

Comment: Do `ogrinfo -so -al` But @dmci, I do not understand one bit in your answer: for GDAL shapefiles have always one layer and its name is the basename of the shapefile. How can you get name "mytable" instead of "myshapefile"?

Comment: Thanks! The output from that command is in the original question.

Comment: @user30184 - totally agree - but I was replicating the naming conventions that the OP had used in their question. For consistency, I've updated my own answer

Comment: @user30184 I'm still not sure how to get the name of the geometry column - where in the output is it found? Thank you!

Comment: Ok, it seems to be driver specific. Some drivers report it like `Geometry Column = GEOMETRY` with ogrinfo -so -al but shapefile driver does not.  With shapefiles I suppose that the name is "OGR_GEOMETRY" for OGR SQL dialect (see special fields in http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html) and "geometry" for SQLite dialect.

Answer (score 4):

Using QGIS, you may run this simple code for printing the total area of the shapefile (I assume you are evaluating the area in a projected reference system):

```py
from qgis.core import *

filepath = 'C:/Users/path_to_the_shapefile/shapefile.shp'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(filepath, 'layer' , 'ogr')

area = 0
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    area += feat.geometry().area()

print area # total area in square meters

print area/10000 # total area in hectares
```